# Arithmetic progression to 7561

Tags: beginner, erlang

I'm new to Erlang and this is my first code in that. As Erlang has no loop statements, the only way I could think of doing this is as follows:

```
-module(verschickten).
-export([f/0]).

f() -> io:format("~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p ~p",
                 [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63,65,67,69,71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,87,89,91,93,95,97,99,101,103,105,107,109,111,113,115,117,119,121,123,125,127,129,131,133,135,137,139,141,143,145,147,149,151,153,155,157,159,161,163,165,167,169,171,173,175,177,179,181,183,185,187,189,191,193,195,197,199,201,203,205,207,209,211,213,215,217,219,221,223,225,227,229,231,233,235,237,239,241,243,245,247,249,251,253,255,257,259,261,263,265,267,269,271,273,275,277,279,281,283,285,287,289,291,293,295,297,299,301,303,305,307,309,311,313,315,317,319,321,323,325,327,329,331,333,335,337,339,341,343,345,347,349,351,353,355,357,359,361,363,365,367,369,371,373,375,377,379,381,383,385,387,389,391,393,395,397,399,401,403,405,407,409,411,413,415,417,419,421,423,425,427,429,431,433,435,437,439,441,443,445,447,449,451,453,455,457,459,461,463,465,467,469,471,473,475,477,479,481,483,485,487,489,491,493,495,497,499,501,503,505,507,509,511,513,515,517,519,521,523,525,527,529,531,533,535,537,539,541,543,545,547,549,551,553,555,557,559,561,563,565,567,569,571,573,575,577,579,581,583,585,587,589,591,593,595,597,599,601,603,605,607,609,611,613,615,617,619,621,623,625,627,629,631,633,635,637,639,641,643,645,647,649,651,653,655,657,659,661,663,665,667,669,671,673,675,677,679,681,683,685,687,689,691,693,695,697,699,701,703,705,707,709,711,713,715,717,719,721,723,725,727,729,731,733,735,737,739,741,743,745,747,749,751,753,755,757,759,761,763,765,767,769,771,773,775,777,779,781,783,785,787,789,791,793,795,797,799,801,803,805,807,809,811,813,815,817,819,821,823,825,827,829,831,833,835,837,839,841,843,845,847,849,851,853,855,857,859,861,863,865,867,869,871,873,875,877,879,881,883,885,887,889,891,893,895,897,899,901,903,905,907,909,911,913,915,917,919,921,923,925,927,929,931,933,935,937,939,941,943,945,947,949,951,953,955,957,959,961,963,965,967,969,971,973,975,977,979,981,983,985,987,989,991,993,995,997,999,1001,1003,1005,1007,1009,1011,1013,1015,1017,1019,1021,1023,1025,1027,1029,1031,1033,1035,1037,1039,1041,1043,1045,1047,1049,1051,1053,1055,1057,1059,1061,1063,1065,1067,1069,1071,1073,1075,1077,1079,1081,1083,1085,1087,1089,1091,1093,1095,1097,1099,1101,1103,1105,1107,1109,1111,1113,1115,1117,1119,1121,1123,1125,1127,1129,1131,1133,1135,1137,1139,1141,1143,1145,1147,1149,1151,1153,1155,1157,1159,1161,1163,1165,1167,1169,1171,1173,1175,1177,1179,1181,1183,1185,1187,1189,1191,1193,1195,1197,1199,1201,1203,1205,1207,1209,1211,1213,1215,1217,1219,1221,1223,1225,1227,1229,1231,1233,1235,1237,1239,1241,1243,1245,1247,1249,1251,1253,1255,1257,1259,1261,1263,1265,1267,1269,1271,1273,1275,1277,1279,1281,1283,1285,1287,1289,1291,1293,1295,1297,1299,1301,1303,1305,1307,1309,1311,1313,1315,1317,1319,1321,1323,1325,1327,1329,1331,1333,1335,1337,1339,1341,1343,1345,1347,1349,1351,1353,1355,1357,1359,1361,1363,1365,1367,1369,1371,1373,1375,1377,1379,1381,1383,1385,1387,1389,1391,1393,1395,1397,1399,1401,1403,1405,1407,1409,1411,1413,1415,1417,1419,1421,1423,1425,1427,1429,1431,1433,1435,1437,1439,1441,1443,1445,1447,1449,1451,1453,1455,1457,1459,1461,1463,1465,1467,1469,1471,1473,1475,1477,1479,1481,1483,1485,1487,1489,1491,1493,1495,1497,1499,1501,1503,1505,1507,1509,1511,1513,1515,1517,1519,1521,1523,1525,1527,1529,1531,1533,1535,1537,1539,1541,1543,1545,1547,1549,1551,1553,1555,1557,1559,1561,1563,1565,1567,1569,1571,1573,1575,1577,1579,1581,1583,1585,1587,1589,1591,1593,1595,1597,1599,1601,1603,1605,1607,1609,1611,1613,1615,1617,1619,1621,1623,1625,1627,1629,1631,1633,1635,1637,1639,1641,1643,1645,1647,1649,1651,1653,1655,1657,1659,1661,1663,1665,1667,1669,1671,1673,1675,1677,1679,1681,1683,1685,1687,1689,1691,1693,1695,1697,1699,1701,1703,1705,1707,1709,1711,1713,1715,1717,1719,1721,1723,1725,1727,1729,1731,1733,1735,1737,1739,1741,1743,1745,1747,1749,1751,1753,1755,1757,1759,1761,1763,1765,1767,1769,1771,1773,1775,1777,1779,1781,1783,1785,1787,1789,1791,1793,1795,1797,1799,1801,1803,1805,1807,1809,1811,1813,1815,1817,1819,1821,1823,1825,1827,1829,1831,1833,1835,1837,1839,1841,1843,1845,1847,1849,1851,1853,1855,1857,1859,1861,1863,1865,1867,1869,1871,1873,1875,1877,1879,1881,1883,1885,1887,1889,1891,1893,1895,1897,1899,1901,1903,1905,1907,1909,1911,1913,1915,1917,1919,1921,1923,1925,1927,1929,1931,1933,1935,1937,1939,1941,1943,1945,1947,1949,1951,1953,1955,1957,1959,1961,1963,1965,1967,1969,1971,1973,1975,1977,1979,1981,1983,1985,1987,1989,1991,1993,1995,1997,1999,2001,2003,2005,2007,2009,2011,2013,2015,2017,2019,2021,2023,2025,2027,2029,2031,2033,2035,2037,2039,2041,2043,2045,2047,2049,2051,2053,2055,2057,2059,2061,2063,2065,2067,2069,2071,2073,2075,2077,2079,2081,2083,2085,2087,2089,2091,2093,2095,2097,2099,2101,2103,2105,2107,2109,2111,2113,2115,2117,2119,2121,2123,2125,2127,2129,2131,2133,2135,2137,2139,2141,2143,2145,2147,2149,2151,2153,2155,2157,2159,2161,2163,2165,2167,2169,2171,2173,2175,2177,2179,2181,2183,2185,2187,2189,2191,2193,2195,2197,2199,2201,2203,2205,2207,2209,2211,2213,2215,2217,2219,2221,2223,2225,2227,2229,2231,2233,2235,2237,2239,2241,2243,2245,2247,2249,2251,2253,2255,2257,2259,2261,2263,2265,2267,2269,2271,2273,2275,2277,2279,2281,2283,2285,2287,2289,2291,2293,2295,2297,2299,2301,2303,2305,2307,2309,2311,2313,2315,2317,2319,2321,2323,2325,2327,2329,2331,2333,2335,2337,2339,2341,2343,2345,2347,2349,2351,2353,2355,2357,2359,2361,2363,2365,2367,2369,2371,2373,2375,2377,2379,2381,2383,2385,2387,2389,2391,2393,2395,2397,2399,2401,2403,2405,2407,2409,2411,2413,2415,2417,2419,2421,2423,2425,2427,2429,2431,2433,2435,2437,2439,2441,2443,2445,2447,2449,2451,2453,2455,2457,2459,2461,2463,2465,2467,2469,2471,2473,2475,2477,2479,2481,2483,2485,2487,2489,2491,2493,2495,2497,2499,2501,2503,2505,2507,2509,2511,2513,2515,2517,2519,2521,2523,2525,2527,2529,2531,2533,2535,2537,2539,2541,2543,2545,2547,2549,2551,2553,2555,2557,2559,2561,2563,2565,2567,2569,2571,2573,2575,2577,2579,2581,2583,2585,2587,2589,2591,2593,2595,2597,2599,2601,2603,2605,2607,2609,2611,2613,2615,2617,2619,2621,2623,2625,2627,2629,2631,2633,2635,2637,2639,2641,2643,2645,2647,2649,2651,2653,2655,2657,2659,2661,2663,2665,2667,2669,2671,2673,2675,2677,2679,2681,2683,2685,2687,2689,2691,2693,2695,2697,2699,2701,2703,2705,2707,2709,2711,2713,2715,2717,2719,2721,2723,2725,2727,2729,2731,2733,2735,2737,2739,2741,2743,2745,2747,2749,2751,2753,2755,2757,2759,2761,2763,2765,2767,2769,2771,2773,2775,2777,2779,2781,2783,2785,2787,2789,2791,2793,2795,2797,2799,2801,2803,2805,2807,2809,2811,2813,2815,2817,2819,2821,2823,2825,2827,2829,2831,2833,2835,2837,2839,2841,2843,2845,2847,2849,2851,2853,2855,2857,2859,2861,2863,2865,2867,2869,2871,2873,2875,2877,2879,2881,2883,2885,2887,2889,2891,2893,2895,2897,2899,2901,2903,2905,2907,2909,2911,2913,2915,2917,2919,2921,2923,2925,2927,2929,2931,2933,2935,2937,2939,2941,2943,2945,2947,2949,2951,2953,2955,2957,2959,2961,2963,2965,2967,2969,2971,2973,2975,2977,2979,2981,2983,2985,2987,2989,2991,2993,2995,2997,2999,3001,3003,3005,3007,3009,3011,3013,3015,3017,3019,3021,3023,3025,3027,3029,3031,3033,3035,3037,3039,3041,3043,3045,3047,3049,3051,3053,3055,3057,3059,3061,3063,3065,3067,3069,3071,3073,3075,3077,3079,3081,3083,3085,3087,3089,3091,3093,3095,3097,3099,3101,3103,3105,3107,3109,3111,3113,3115,3117,3119,3121,3123,3125,3127,3129,3131,3133,3135,3137,3139,3141,3143,3145,3147,3149,3151,3153,3155,3157,3159,3161,3163,3165,3167,3169,3171,3173,3175,3177,3179,3181,3183,3185,3187,3189,3191,3193,3195,3197,3199,3201,3203,3205,3207,3209,3211,3213,3215,3217,3219,3221,3223,3225,3227,3229,3231,3233,3235,3237,3239,3241,3243,3245,3247,3249,3251,3253,3255,3257,3259,3261,3263,3265,3267,3269,3271,3273,3275,3277,3279,3281,3283,3285,3287,3289,3291,3293,3295,3297,3299,3301,3303,3305,3307,3309,3311,3313,3315,3317,3319,3321,3323,3325,3327,3329,3331,3333,3335,3337,3339,3341,3343,3345,3347,3349,3351,3353,3355,3357,3359,3361,3363,3365,3367,3369,3371,3373,3375,3377,3379,3381,3383,3385,3387,3389,3391,3393,3395,3397,3399,3401,3403,3405,3407,3409,3411,3413,3415,3417,3419,3421,3423,3425,3427,3429,3431,3433,3435,3437,3439,3441,3443,3445,3447,3449,3451,3453,3455,3457,3459,3461,3463,3465,3467,3469,3471,3473,3475,3477,3479,3481,3483,3485,3487,3489,3491,3493,3495,3497,3499,3501,3503,3505,3507,3509,3511,3513,3515,3517,3519,3521,3523,3525,3527,3529,3531,3533,3535,3537,3539,3541,3543,3545,3547,3549,3551,3553,3555,3557,3559,3561,3563,3565,3567,3569,3571,3573,3575,3577,3579,3581,3583,3585,3587,3589,3591,3593,3595,3597,3599,3601,3603,3605,3607,3609,3611,3613,3615,3617,3619,3621,3623,3625,3627,3629,3631,3633,3635,3637,3639,3641,3643,3645,3647,3649,3651,3653,3655,3657,3659,3661,3663,3665,3667,3669,3671,3673,3675,3677,3679,3681,3683,3685,3687,3689,3691,3693,3695,3697,3699,3701,3703,3705,3707,3709,3711,3713,3715,3717,3719,3721,3723,3725,3727,3729,3731,3733,3735,3737,3739,3741,3743,3745,3747,3749,3751,3753,3755,3757,3759,3761,3763,3765,3767,3769,3771,3773,3775,3777,3779,3781,3783,3785,3787,3789,3791,3793,3795,3797,3799,3801,3803,3805,3807,3809,3811,3813,3815,3817,3819,3821,3823,3825,3827,3829,3831,3833,3835,3837,3839,3841,3843,3845,3847,3849,3851,3853,3855,3857,3859,3861,3863,3865,3867,3869,3871,3873,3875,3877,3879,3881,3883,3885,3887,3889,3891,3893,3895,3897,3899,3901,3903,3905,3907,3909,3911,3913,3915,3917,3919,3921,3923,3925,3927,3929,3931,3933,3935,3937,3939,3941,3943,3945,3947,3949,3951,3953,3955,3957,3959,3961,3963,3965,3967,3969,3971,3973,3975,3977,3979,3981,3983,3985,3987,3989,3991,3993,3995,3997,3999,4001,4003,4005,4007,4009,4011,4013,4015,4017,4019,4021,4023,4025,4027,4029,4031,4033,4035,4037,4039,4041,4043,4045,4047,4049,4051,4053,4055,4057,4059,4061,4063,4065,4067,4069,4071,4073,4075,4077,4079,4081,4083,4085,4087,4089,4091,4093,4095,4097,4099,4101,4103,4105,4107,4109,4111,4113,4115,4117,4119,4121,4123,4125,4127,4129,4131,4133,4135,4137,4139,4141,4143,4145,4147,4149,4151,4153,4155,4157,4159,4161,4163,4165,4167,4169,4171,4173,4175,4177,4179,4181,4183,4185,4187,4189,4191,4193,4195,4197,4199,4201,4203,4205,4207,4209,4211,4213,4215,4217,4219,4221,4223,4225,4227,4229,4231,4233,4235,4237,4239,4241,4243,4245,4247,4249,4251,4253,4255,4257,4259,4261,4263,4265,4267,4269,4271,4273,4275,4277,4279,4281,4283,4285,4287,4289,4291,4293,4295,4297,4299,4301,4303,4305,4307,4309,4311,4313,4315,4317,4319,4321,4323,4325,4327,4329,4331,4333,4335,4337,4339,4341,4343,4345,4347,4349,4351,4353,4355,4357,4359,4361,4363,4365,4367,4369,4371,4373,4375,4377,4379,4381,4383,4385,4387,4389,4391,4393,4395,4397,4399,4401,4403,4405,4407,4409,4411,4413,4415,4417,4419,4421,4423,4425,4427,4429,4431,4433,4435,4437,4439,4441,4443,4445,4447,4449,4451,4453,4455,4457,4459,4461,4463,4465,4467,4469,4471,4473,4475,4477,4479,4481,4483,4485,4487,4489,4491,4493,4495,4497,4499,4501,4503,4505,4507,4509,4511,4513,4515,4517,4519,4521,4523,4525,4527,4529,4531,4533,4535,4537,4539,4541,4543,4545,4547,4549,4551,4553,4555,4557,4559,4561,4563,4565,4567,4569,4571,4573,4575,4577,4579,4581,4583,4585,4587,4589,4591,4593,4595,4597,4599,4601,4603,4605,4607,4609,4611,4613,4615,4617,4619,4621,4623,4625,4627,4629,4631,4633,4635,4637,4639,4641,4643,4645,4647,4649,4651,4653,4655,4657,4659,4661,4663,4665,4667,4669,4671,4673,4675,4677,4679,4681,4683,4685,4687,4689,4691,4693,4695,4697,4699,4701,4703,4705,4707,4709,4711,4713,4715,4717,4719,4721,4723,4725,4727,4729,4731,4733,4735,4737,4739,4741,4743,4745,4747,4749,4751,4753,4755,4757,4759,4761,4763,4765,4767,4769,4771,4773,4775,4777,4779,4781,4783,4785,4787,4789,4791,4793,4795,4797,4799,4801,4803,4805,4807,4809,4811,4813,4815,4817,4819,4821,4823,4825,4827,4829,4831,4833,4835,4837,4839,4841,4843,4845,4847,4849,4851,4853,4855,4857,4859,4861,4863,4865,4867,4869,4871,4873,4875,4877,4879,4881,4883,4885,4887,4889,4891,4893,4895,4897,4899,4901,4903,4905,4907,4909,4911,4913,4915,4917,4919,4921,4923,4925,4927,4929,4931,4933,4935,4937,4939,4941,4943,4945,4947,4949,4951,4953,4955,4957,4959,4961,4963,4965,4967,4969,4971,4973,4975,4977,4979,4981,4983,4985,4987,4989,4991,4993,4995,4997,4999,5001,5003,5005,5007,5009,5011,5013,5015,5017,5019,5021,5023,5025,5027,5029,5031,5033,5035,5037,5039,5041,5043,5045,5047,5049,5051,5053,5055,5057,5059,5061,5063,5065,5067,5069,5071,5073,5075,5077,5079,5081,5083,5085,5087,5089,5091,5093,5095,5097,5099,5101,5103,5105,5107,5109,5111,5113,5115,5117,5119,5121,5123,5125,5127,5129,5131,5133,5135,5137,5139,5141,5143,5145,5147,5149,5151,5153,5155,5157,5159,5161,5163,5165,5167,5169,5171,5173,5175,5177,5179,5181,5183,5185,5187,5189,5191,5193,5195,5197,5199,5201,5203,5205,5207,5209,5211,5213,5215,5217,5219,5221,5223,5225,5227,5229,5231,5233,5235,5237,5239,5241,5243,5245,5247,5249,5251,5253,5255,5257,5259,5261,5263,5265,5267,5269,5271,5273,5275,5277,5279,5281,5283,5285,5287,5289,5291,5293,5295,5297,5299,5301,5303,5305,5307,5309,5311,5313,5315,5317,5319,5321,5323,5325,5327,5329,5331,5333,5335,5337,5339,5341,5343,5345,5347,5349,5351,5353,5355,5357,5359,5361,5363,5365,5367,5369,5371,5373,5375,5377,5379,5381,5383,5385,5387,5389,5391,5393,5395,5397,5399,5401,5403,5405,5407,5409,5411,5413,5415,5417,5419,5421,5423,5425,5427,5429,5431,5433,5435,5437,5439,5441,5443,5445,5447,5449,5451,5453,5455,5457,5459,5461,5463,5465,5467,5469,5471,5473,5475,5477,5479,5481,5483,5485,5487,5489,5491,5493,5495,5497,5499,5501,5503,5505,5507,5509,5511,5513,5515,5517,5519,5521,5523,5525,5527,5529,5531,5533,5535,5537,5539,5541,5543,5545,5547,5549,5551,5553,5555,5557,5559,5561,5563,5565,5567,5569,5571,5573,5575,5577,5579,5581,5583,5585,5587,5589,5591,5593,5595,5597,5599,5601,5603,5605,5607,5609,5611,5613,5615,5617,5619,5621,5623,5625,5627,5629,5631,5633,5635,5637,5639,5641,5643,5645,5647,5649,5651,5653,5655,5657,5659,5661,5663,5665,5667,5669,5671,5673,5675,5677,5679,5681,5683,5685,5687,5689,5691,5693,5695,5697,5699,5701,5703,5705,5707,5709,5711,5713,5715,5717,5719,5721,5723,5725,5727,5729,5731,5733,5735,5737,5739,5741,5743,5745,5747,5749,5751,5753,5755,5757,5759,5761,5763,5765,5767,5769,5771,5773,5775,5777,5779,5781,5783,5785,5787,5789,5791,5793,5795,5797,5799,5801,5803,5805,5807,5809,5811,5813,5815,5817,5819,5821,5823,5825,5827,5829,5831,5833,5835,5837,5839,5841,5843,5845,5847,5849,5851,5853,5855,5857,5859,5861,5863,5865,5867,5869,5871,5873,5875,5877,5879,5881,5883,5885,5887,5889,5891,5893,5895,5897,5899,5901,5903,5905,5907,5909,5911,5913,5915,5917,5919,5921,5923,5925,5927,5929,5931,5933,5935,5937,5939,5941,5943,5945,5947,5949,5951,5953,5955,5957,5959,5961,5963,5965,5967,5969,5971,5973,5975,5977,5979,5981,5983,5985,5987,5989,5991,5993,5995,5997,5999,6001,6003,6005,6007,6009,6011,6013,6015,6017,6019,6021,6023,6025,6027,6029,6031,6033,6035,6037,6039,6041,6043,6045,6047,6049,6051,6053,6055,6057,6059,6061,6063,6065,6067,6069,6071,6073,6075,6077,6079,6081,6083,6085,6087,6089,6091,6093,6095,6097,6099,6101,6103,6105,6107,6109,6111,6113,6115,6117,6119,6121,6123,6125,6127,6129,6131,6133,6135,6137,6139,6141,6143,6145,6147,6149,6151,6153,6155,6157,6159,6161,6163,6165,6167,6169,6171,6173,6175,6177,6179,6181,6183,6185,6187,6189,6191,6193,6195,6197,6199,6201,6203,6205,6207,6209,6211,6213,6215,6217,6219,6221,6223,6225,6227,6229,6231,6233,6235,6237,6239,6241,6243,6245,6247,6249,6251,6253,6255,6257,6259,6261,6263,6265,6267,6269,6271,6273,6275,6277,6279,6281,6283,6285,6287,6289,6291,6293,6295,6297,6299,6301,6303,6305,6307,6309,6311,6313,6315,6317,6319,6321,6323,6325,6327,6329,6331,6333,6335,6337,6339,6341,6343,6345,6347,6349,6351,6353,6355,6357,6359,6361,6363,6365,6367,6369,6371,6373,6375,6377,6379,6381,6383,6385,6387,6389,6391,6393,6395,6397,6399,6401,6403,6405,6407,6409,6411,6413,6415,6417,6419,6421,6423,6425,6427,6429,6431,6433,6435,6437,6439,6441,6443,6445,6447,6449,6451,6453,6455,6457,6459,6461,6463,6465,6467,6469,6471,6473,6475,6477,6479,6481,6483,6485,6487,6489,6491,6493,6495,6497,6499,6501,6503,6505,6507,6509,6511,6513,6515,6517,6519,6521,6523,6525,6527,6529,6531,6533,6535,6537,6539,6541,6543,6545,6547,6549,6551,6553,6555,6557,6559,6561,6563,6565,6567,6569,6571,6573,6575,6577,6579,6581,6583,6585,6587,6589,6591,6593,6595,6597,6599,6601,6603,6605,6607,6609,6611,6613,6615,6617,6619,6621,6623,6625,6627,6629,6631,6633,6635,6637,6639,6641,6643,6645,6647,6649,6651,6653,6655,6657,6659,6661,6663,6665,6667,6669,6671,6673,6675,6677,6679,6681,6683,6685,6687,6689,6691,6693,6695,6697,6699,6701,6703,6705,6707,6709,6711,6713,6715,6717,6719,6721,6723,6725,6727,6729,6731,6733,6735,6737,6739,6741,6743,6745,6747,6749,6751,6753,6755,6757,6759,6761,6763,6765,6767,6769,6771,6773,6775,6777,6779,6781,6783,6785,6787,6789,6791,6793,6795,6797,6799,6801,6803,6805,6807,6809,6811,6813,6815,6817,6819,6821,6823,6825,6827,6829,6831,6833,6835,6837,6839,6841,6843,6845,6847,6849,6851,6853,6855,6857,6859,6861,6863,6865,6867,6869,6871,6873,6875,6877,6879,6881,6883,6885,6887,6889,6891,6893,6895,6897,6899,6901,6903,6905,6907,6909,6911,6913,6915,6917,6919,6921,6923,6925,6927,6929,6931,6933,6935,6937,6939,6941,6943,6945,6947,6949,6951,6953,6955,6957,6959,6961,6963,6965,6967,6969,6971,6973,6975,6977,6979,6981,6983,6985,6987,6989,6991,6993,6995,6997,6999,7001,7003,7005,7007,7009,7011,7013,7015,7017,7019,7021,7023,7025,7027,7029,7031,7033,7035,7037,7039,7041,7043,7045,7047,7049,7051,7053,7055,7057,7059,7061,7063,7065,7067,7069,7071,7073,7075,7077,7079,7081,7083,7085,7087,7089,7091,7093,7095,7097,7099,7101,7103,7105,7107,7109,7111,7113,7115,7117,7119,7121,7123,7125,7127,7129,7131,7133,7135,7137,7139,7141,7143,7145,7147,7149,7151,7153,7155,7157,7159,7161,7163,7165,7167,7169,7171,7173,7175,7177,7179,7181,7183,7185,7187,7189,7191,7193,7195,7197,7199,7201,7203,7205,7207,7209,7211,7213,7215,7217,7219,7221,7223,7225,7227,7229,7231,7233,7235,7237,7239,7241,7243,7245,7247,7249,7251,7253,7255,7257,7259,7261,7263,7265,7267,7269,7271,7273,7275,7277,7279,7281,7283,7285,7287,7289,7291,7293,7295,7297,7299,7301,7303,7305,7307,7309,7311,7313,7315,7317,7319,7321,7323,7325,7327,7329,7331,7333,7335,7337,7339,7341,7343,7345,7347,7349,7351,7353,7355,7357,7359,7361,7363,7365,7367,7369,7371,7373,7375,7377,7379,7381,7383,7385,7387,7389,7391,7393,7395,7397,7399,7401,7403,7405,7407,7409,7411,7413,7415,7417,7419,7421,7423,7425,7427,7429,7431,7433,7435,7437,7439,7441,7443,7445,7447,7449,7451,7453,7455,7457,7459,7461,7463,7465,7467,7469,7471,7473,7475,7477,7479,7481,7483,7485,7487,7489,7491,7493,7495,7497,7499,7501,7503,7505,7507,7509,7511,7513,7515,7517,7519,7521,7523,7525,7527,7529,7531,7533,7535,7537,7539,7541,7543,7545,7547,7549,7551,7553,7555,7557,7559,7561]).
```

How could I write it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lists:seq` and `lists:map` they were made for that purpose. These are basic functional building blocks and as important as recursion. Also look at `lists:foldl` and `lists:foldr` and lambda-expressions (fun()->...).

```
-module(verschickten).
-export([f/0]).

f() -> lists:map(fun(I) -> io:format("~p ", [I]) end, lists:seq(1, 7561, 2)).
```

Comment: This would be even better if you use `lists:foreach/2` instead of `lists:map/2`, as you do not care about/use the return values.

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: worked for me thx

Answer (score 1):

I would use recursion here:

```
-module(arith_progr).
-export([progr/3]).

progr(Start, _Increment, End) when Start > End ->
    io:format("~n");
progr(Start, Increment, End) ->
    io:format("~p ", [Start]),
    progr(Start+Increment, Increment, End).
```

This will print numbers from Start with increment=Increment until number is beyond End.

Comment: this will use up all stack

Comment: It shouldn't. The Erlang compiler is optimized for tail recursion; see http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion